# pattern validation for decimal json schema

Tags: json, regex, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

We need to match the below scenarios in JSON schema for a number format.

the number should accept in an only decimal format like 5.0/5.1, it should not accept whole number format like 4/5/6.

The number should not accept more than 11 decimal places (e.g 5.111111111111 should throw an error because it has 12 decimal places, but 5.111 should be accepted as it has 3 decimal places)

I have tried below JSON schema, but it's not working

```
"myscore": {
        "type": "number",
        "multipleOf": 0.00000000001,
        "not": {
            "multipleOf": 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: (1) the values `5` and `5.0` are equal – I cannot see any business reason why you would allow only one particular representation (`5.000000000000` would then also be invalid because it has 12 decimal places?); (2) `multipleOf` seems to be the right choice to limit the number of decimal places but unfortunately suffers from conversion/rounding which makes it unreliable here.

Comment: `{not: {multipleOf: 1 } }` will fail 5.0 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to send the number as a string and use regex to validate it.

> Mathematical Integers
>
> Some programming languages and parsers use different internal
>   representations for floating point numbers than they do for integers.
>
> For consistency, integer JSON numbers SHOULD NOT be encoded with a
>   fractional part.

http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.6.3

If you specifically want to store `5.0`, you're storing a string, because it IS equivilent to `5` as far as numbers are concerned.